# login form without database in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dreamweaver

I am trying to create a simple Login form without database connection in vb.net but I am getting error when tried to execute it.

My code is:

```
<script runat="server">
Sub Page_Load
    If (txtuname.Text == "xxx") AND (txtpass.Text == "xxx") Then
        response.write("Welcome user")
        Server.Transfer("login2.aspx")
    Else
        response.write("Invalid username and password")
        Server.Transfer("login.aspx")
    End IF
End sub
</script>
```

And the error I am getting is:

> Expression expected at:If (txtuname.Text == "xxx") AND (txtpass.Text == "xxx") Then

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

As this is vb, it should be:

```
If (txtuname.Text = "xxx") AND (txtpass.Text = "xxx") Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `If (txtuname.Text = "xxx") AND (txtpass.Text = "xxx") Then` in place of your code also you can use an xml file to store username and password detail